# Interesting sequence in size of coprime equivalence classes

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

In the course of computation for a Project Euler problem, I was testing a function and noticed a strange pattern.

Take the natural numbers $\{2 , 3 , \dots n\}$. Call $a \sim b$ iff all natural numbers coprime to $a$ are also coprime to $b$ and vice-versa. This is the same as saying that they have the same prime factorisation if we ignore the exponents.

Call $f(n)$ the number of equivalence classes
$$f(n) = \left|(\{2,3,\dots n\}/\sim) \right|$$

Example for **n = 10**: The equivalence classes are $\{\{2,4,8\},\{3,9\},\{6\},\{5\},\{7\},\{10\}\}$

Example for **n = 20**: The equivalence classes are $\{\{2,4,8,16\},\{3,9\},\{6,12,18\},\{5\},\{10,20\},\{7\},\{11\},\{13\},\{14\},\{15\},\{17\},\{19\}\}$

Here are some sample values for $f$ for powers of $10$:

$$\begin{align}
f(10) &= 6 \\
f(100) &= 60 \\
f(1000) &= 607 \\
f(10000) &= 6082 \\
f(100000) &= 60793 \\
f(1000000) &= 607925
\end{align}$$

Call me superstitious, but this looks like a pattern. In fact, it looks like [the decimal expansion](https://oeis.org/A059956) of $6/\pi^2$.

---

Does anyone know if there's a genuine pattern here, and why?

Comment: A list of the equivalence classes for $n=10$ would be useful here as an example of what $f(n)$ stands for (which for the case of $n=10$, I believe to be counting the sets $\{2,4,8\},\{3,9\},\{1\},\{5\},\{6\},\{7\}$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to think of $f(n)$ is as the number of squarefree numbers below $n$, since there is exactly one squarefree number in each of the equivalence classes you describe, and squarefree number is the smallest element of each class. Thus, $f(n)/n$ is the fraction of numbers under $n$ which are squarefree.

For a given prime $p$, as $n$ goes to infinity, $1-1/p^2$ of the numbers below $n$ are not divisible by $p^2$. Informally, the fraction of numbers below $n$ not divisible by the square of any prime should be about
$$ \prod_{p} (1 - p^{-2}) = \left(\prod_{p} \frac{1}{1 - p^{-2}} \right)^{-1} = \frac{1}{\zeta(2)} = \frac{6}{\pi^2}$$

Comment: I was editing my answer when you post yours :) So I would post a rigorous(though famous) proof instead.

Comment: Doesn't this presume that no number is divisible by two squares of primes? This disjointness would lend credence to the heuristic you outline. Without it, I find it surprising that it still works.

Comment: @Myridium The idea is that each equivalence class is completely identified by the smallest number in it, which is square-free. For example, if a equivalence class consists of $p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\ldots p_k^{\alpha_k}$, where $\alpha_i>0$, then $p_1p_2\ldots p_k$ is such a number.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @BoltonBailey explains it very well. I'll just add some trivial details about the computation. In fact, $n$ is square-free iff $\mu(n)\not=0$, i.e., $(\mu(n))^2=1$. So $f(n)/n$ evaluates to
\begin{align}\frac{f(n)}n & =\frac 1 n \sum_{i\leq n}(\mu(i))^2\\
& = \frac 1 n\sum_{i\leq n}\sum_{d^2\mid i}\mu(d)\\
& =\frac 1 n\sum_{d\leq\sqrt n}\mu(d)\left(\frac{n}{d^2}+O(1)\right)\\
& =\sum_{d\leq\sqrt n}\frac{\mu(d)}{d^2}+O(n^{-1/2})\\
& =\frac 1 {\zeta(2)}+O(n^{-1/2})\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Welp, perhaps I should have deleted my question instead, as I soon saw this quote on the OEIS (Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences):

> $6/\pi^2$ is the probability that two randomly selected numbers will be coprime

However, this still leaves the question of *why*.

Comment: The wikipedia page on coprime numbers has a good explanation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers